# How to Show UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, ios4, edit

I have a tableview which has a list of options the user has selcected( It is an edit page ).

the tableview looks as below

> Apple                     `UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark`
>
> Orange                  `UITableViewCellAccessoryNone`
>
> Pineapple             `UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark`   Banana
>   `UITableViewCellAccessoryNone`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

  self.mySavedFruitsArray = [myDBOperations getMyFruitsList:[appDelegate getDBPath]:self.myId];

}

/ Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:
(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"PoemTypeCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"]autorelease];

    }

   NSDictionary *aDict = [self.myFruitsArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   NSString *aValue = [aDict objectForKey:@"value"];
   NSString *aId = [aDict objectForKey:@"key"];
   cell.textLabel.text = aValue;
   cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

   NSDictionary *aSavedDict = [self.mySavedFruitsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *Value = [aSavedDict objectForKey:@"value"];
    NSString *Id = [aSavedDict objectForKey:@"key"];
    if ( aId == Id ){
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }else
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }    

  return cell;

}
```

`mySavedFruitsArray` - it holds the user selected fruits.

`myFruitsArr` - this has common list of fruits

now i would like to know how to display `UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark` for cell which matches with `mySavedFruitsArray`.

I mean , in this edit view i want to display the fruits list with user selected option.

Pls let me know how to do that.

I tried like this, but no use.

```
/ Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:
(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"PoemTypeCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"]autorelease];

    }

   NSDictionary *aDict = [self.myFruitsArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   NSString *aValue = [aDict objectForKey:@"value"];
   NSString *aId = [aDict objectForKey:@"key"];
   cell.textLabel.text = aValue;
   cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

   NSDictionary *aSavedDict = [self.mySavedFruitsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *Value = [aSavedDict objectForKey:@"value"];
    NSString *Id = [aSavedDict objectForKey:@"key"];
    if ( aId == Id ){
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }else
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }    

  return cell;

}
```

pls note self.mySavedFruitsArray may not be equal to myFruitsArr always ( because user may select only one fruit).

Answer (score 2):

```
if ( aId == Id ){
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }else
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
```

string comparison is wrong. You should compare strings this way:

```
if([aId isEqualToString:Id]) {
....
}
```

Comment: pls note self.mySavedFruitsArray may not be equal to myFruitsArr.

Comment: NSDictionary *aSavedDict = [self.mySavedFruitsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 this line would crash when count is lesser than myFruitsArr or indexpath.row

Answer (score 1):

instead of checking  if ( aId == Id ) which compares the strings as identical objects, 
use if ([aID isEqualToString:Id]) which compares strings

Comment: i amgetting crash when scroling

Comment: you are creating a cell identifier "PoemTypeCell", and if cell is nil, you are recreating the cell using another identifier "MyIdentifier". try using the same identifier

Answer (score 0):

In a version downloaded yesterday (6/8/14), `UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark` and `UITableViewCellAccessoryNone` is not valid. It was throwing compiler errors for me. I think you are supposed to use it as an enum, like so:

```
    if item.completed {
        cell!.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
    } else {
        cell!.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
    }
```

With this change, my code compiles and the behavior appears in the simulator.
Sorry I don't know which version to look up (UIKit?), I'm new to iOS development.